# python code not working while trying to make a game

Tags: python

```
import random #imports random module
username = ""
lvl = 0
exp = 0
maxexp = 50
oldexp = 0

def newgame():  # Used for creating a New Account
    username = raw_input("Enter your new nickname : ")
    lvl = 0
    exp = 0
    return lvl
    return exp
    return username
    userinfo(username,lvl,exp)  

def userinfo(username,lvl,exp):
        print lvl,exp
        return lvl
        return exp
        return username
        update_userinfo(lvl,exp,0,0)

def update_userinfo(exp,lvl,maxexp,exp_increase):
    exp_up(exp,exp_increase)
    return exp
    if exp >= maxexp:
        exp = exp - maxexp
        lvl_up(lvl,1)
        maxexp = maxexp * 2
        print "You lvled up"

def exp_up(exp,exp_increase):
    exp = exp + exp_increase

def lvl_up(lvl,lvl_increase):
    lvl = lvl + lvl_increase
    return lvl


def kanto():
    print "Welcome new trainer! You are going to begin your game at the Kanto region. Here you will meet variety types of Pokemons. In this world of pokemons your objective is to Find and Catch as many Pokemons as you can. There are also many challenges that you may face along your adventure. Make sure you face them with your upmost courage and deal with them with all your might. May you be the next Pokemon champion."

def johto():
        print "Welcome new trainer! You are going to begin your game at the Johto region. Here you will meet variety types of Pokemons. In this world of pokemons your objective is to Find and Catch as many Pokemons as you can. There are also many challenges that you may face along your adventure. Make sure you face them with your upmost courage and deal with them with all your might. May you be the next Pokemon champion."

def hoenn():
        print "Welcome new trainer! You are going to begin your game at the Hoenn region. Here you will meet variety types of Pokemons. In this world of pokemons your objective is to Find and Catch as many Pokemons as you can. There are also many challenges that you may face along your adventure. Make sure you face them with your upmost courage and deal with them with all your might. May you be the next Pokemon champion."

def gamestart():
    min = 1
    max = 3
    region = random.randint(min,max)
    if region == 1:
        kanto()
    elif region == 2:
        johto()
    elif region == 3:
        hoenn()

def choose_pokemon_kanto():
    print "Proffessor : Ok.... Lets see. We have three Pokeballs here, and all of them have one pokemon that I had caught in my last field trip. I raised all of them to about level 5, and taught them 2 moves, best for beginners right?"
    cont = raw_input("")
    print "Proffessor : First here we have "


update_userinfo(exp,lvl,maxexp,60)
```

I was trying to learn python a little bit and tried making a text based pokemon game. The part that is not working is :

```
update_userinfo(exp,lvl,maxexp,60)
```

I am new to coding so please help with this.Should I use functions that much, or just use if else statements and do the entire code? Why doesn't python change the value of a variable when a function to change the value of that variable is executed.

Comment: You might be needing a main function to call `update_userinfo` if it is not being called in some other way

Comment: You don't really change variables, you change what a name refers to. If the name is local to a function (e.g a parameter), all you will do is change what that local name refers to.

Comment: I don't program in Python much, but do the multiple return statements in some of your functions (i.e. newgame()) do anything?  Don't you need to do something like:  "return (lvl,exp,username)"?

Comment: It changes the variable but those changes are local to the function. You can use Global variables or return the updated values to reflect the changes or use a different data structure like lists in which you can make the changes inside the function and changes would be reflected to other functions as well

Comment: function `update_userinfo` returns right after the `return` statement and rest of the lines in the function is not executed. Can you give a concrete example of what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of mistakes there, but I guess you just want to return exp after using `exp_up`

```
def exp_up(exp,exp_increase):
    exp = exp + exp_increase
```

You decalare new variable exp, that is accesible only inside function exp_up. If you want to use this in `update_user_info` function, you need to return that `exp` from `exp_up` function. So your `exp_up` would look like this:

```
def exp_up(exp,exp_increase):
    exp = exp + exp_increase
    return exp
```

and your `update_userinfo`

```
def update_userinfo(exp,lvl,maxexp,exp_increase):
    exp = exp_up(exp,exp_increase)
    return exp
    ...
```